# How to convert unix timestamp correctly to BST or GMT depending on the date?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I can easily write a clumsy function to do this, but is there an easy way to get the "correct" local UK date/time from a timestamp, rather than it always being GMT (which at certain times of year - like now - would be an hour behind).

Thanks

Comment: Yes, by setting your [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: Use the timezone `Europe/London` and let PHP do the work, either using a `DateTime` object or the older `date` API…

Answer (score 1):

The exact date when the UK changes timezone changes by year, so I wouldn't recommend trying to implement the logic yourself. You can initialise a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object to the correct timezone (Europe/London), and then set it to your timestamp:

```
<?php
$timestamp = 1500000000;

$dateTime = new \DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$dateTime->setTimestamp($timestamp);

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// 2017-07-14 03:40:00
```